# How do I get list of stocktwit watchlists of an user in jquery

Tags: jquery, stocktwits

I want to retrieve a list of all watch lists created by a user to show in my custom MVC4 application.

I could authenticate the user and could also get the watchlist feed if I knew the watchlistid. In our application, we want the user to select his existing watchlist to show the feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from nowhere in Stocktwits, I found this document incredibly helpful:

http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/signin

Once you've gotten the flow going, replace the AJAX call to something more like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/watchlists.json?callback=?", 
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 5000,
        data:{ access_token: token},
        success: function(data) {
           if (data) {
           callback(data);
         }},
        error: function(error){
         //handle error
         }
```

Now we have a watchlist. After that, you want to write a callback function to use the data you just obtained:

```
var getWatchlist = function(data){
    if(!data) return undefined;     //Sanity checks are always good!
    if(data.response == undefined) return undefined;

      var postInfo = [];  //A list to put our results on!

  if(data.response.status == "401") { //Represents a bad token. Handle and return
     return;
  }
  var watchlistData = data.watchlists;
  for (var i=0; i<watchlistData.length; i++)
  {
    var watchlistId = watchlistData[i].id;

    var tempInfo = {watchlistId};
    postInfo.push(tempInfo);
  }
return postInfo;    //All of your watchlists!
}
```

From here, use the similar function described here:

http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#watchlists-show-docs

```
$.ajax({          //Note you have to put in the watchlist_id
        url: "https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/watchlists/show/"+watchlist_id+".json?callback=?", 
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 5000,
        data:{ access_token: token},
        success: function(data) {
           if (data) {
           callback(data);
         }},
        error: function(error){
         //handle error
         }
```

Do the same sort of thing again with a different callback:

```
var getWatchlistData = function(data){
    if(!data) return undefined;    //Sanity is still important, for some....
    if(data.response == undefined) return undefined;

     var postInfo = [];  //A list to put our results on!

  if(data.response.status == "401") { //Represents a bad token. Handle and return
     return;
  }
  var watchlistSymbolsData = data.watchlists.symbols;
  for (var i=0; i<watchlistSymbolsData.length; i++)
  {
    var watchlistTicker = watchlistData[i].symbol;
            var watchlistId = watchlistData[i].id;
    var tempInfo = {watchlistTicker, watchlistId};    //You'll probably want some more data here
    postInfo.push(tempInfo);
  }
return postInfo;    //All of your tickers with corresponding ids!
}
```

Simply make a function to call the AJAX, pass in one of those get functions as the callback, and you'll be well on your way to being able to display anything you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to authenticate the user. Once this is done you can use the access token and call the https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/watchlists.json endpoint.

Here is the documentation on this:http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#watchlists-index-docs

This will give you the list of watch lists the user has and then you can use the ID to call the watch list stream.